# How to switch between multiple vim configurations with a command or local vimrc files?

Tags: vim

I work in several groups, each of which has its own tab/indentation/spacing standards in C.

Is there a way to have separate selectable VIM configurations for each so, when I edit a file, either:

- I do something like `set group=1` to select a configuration
- a local .vimrc that lives in the working directory is used to set the configuration automatically

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14407951/1099240

Comment: See also the question [Toggle between two different vim configurations](https://superuser.com/questions/209075) on superuser.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### In Summary

There are a few ways to do this, of which most have been suggested, but I thought I'd summarise them with two extra ones:

- Per-directory vimrc - has the disadvantage that Vim must be started in the right directory: if your project is in `~/project1` and you have `~/project1/.vim.custom` and do `cd ~ ; vim project1/file.c`, the custom settings won't be found.
- Modelines - very effective, but has the disadvantage of needing to add them to all files (and remember to add them to new files)
- Directory specific autocommands - this is very effective
- Scan for a specific header in the file (see below) - this is the one I've used most in the past where working for different companies or on clearly named projects
- Per-directory vimrc that's checked when the file is opened (see below).  Another fairly easy one to implement, especially if your project code is all in one place.

### Scanning for a Header

In a lot of organisations, there's a standard header (with a copyright notice and project name etc) at the top of every source file.  If this is the case, you can get Vim to automatically scan the first (e.g.) 10 lines of the file looking for a keyword.  If it finds it, it can change your settings.  I've modified this to make it simpler than the form I use (which does lots of other things), but create a `~/.vim/after/filetype.vim` (if you don't have one yet) and add something like this:

```
au FileType * call <SID>ConfigureFiletypes(expand("<amatch>"))

" List of file types to customise
let s:GROUPNAMETypes = ['c', 'cpp', 'vhdl', 'c.doxygen']

func! <SID>CheckForGROUPNAMECode()
    " Check if any of the first ten lines contain "GROUPNAME".

    " Read the first ten lines into a variable
    let header = getline(1)
    for i in range(2, 10)
        let header = header . getline(i)
    endfor

    if header =~ '\<GROUPNAME\>'
        " Change the status line to make it clear which
        " group we're using
        setlocal statusline=%<%f\ (GROUPNAME)\ %h%m%r%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P
        " Do other customisation here
        setlocal et
        " etc
    endif
endfunc

func! <SID>ConfigureFiletypes(filetype)
    if index(s:GROUPNAMETypes, a:filetype) != -1
        call <SID>CheckForGROUPNAMECode()
    endif
endfunc
```

Whenever a file of any type is opened and the file type is set (the `au FileType *` line), the `ConfigureFiletypes` function is called.  This checks whether the file type is in the list of file types associated with the current group (GROUPNAME), in this case 'c', 'cpp', 'vhdl' or 'c.doxygen'.  If it is, it calls CheckForGROUPNAMECode(), which reads the first 10 lines of the file and if they contain GROUPNAME, it does some customisation.  As well as setting expandtabs or whatever, this also changes the status bar to show the group name clearly so you know it's worked at a glance.

### Checking for Configuration When Opening

Much like JS Bangs' suggestion, having a custom configuration file can be useful.  However, instead of loading it in vimrc, consider something like this, which will check when a .c file is opened for a .vim.custom in the same directory as the .c file.

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.c call CheckForCustomConfiguration()

function! CheckForCustomConfiguration()
    " Check for .vim.custom in the directory containing the newly opened file
    let custom_config_file = expand('%:p:h') . '/.vim.custom'
    if filereadable(custom_config_file)
        exe 'source' custom_config_file
    endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 66):

I have this in `$HOME/.vimrc`:

```
if filereadable(".vim.custom")
    so .vim.custom
endif
```

This allows me to put a `.vim.custom` file in every directory to load commands and options specific to that directory. If you're working on multiple projects that have deep directory structures you might need something more sophisticated (e.g. walk up the directory tree until a `.vim.custom` is found), but the same basic idea will work.

**UPDATE:**

I now do something like this in order to read a `.vim` file from the same directory as the file I'm editing, regardless of what the current directory is.

```
let b:thisdir=expand("%:p:h")
let b:vim=b:thisdir."/.vim"
if (filereadable(b:vim))
    execute "source ".b:vim
endif
```

Comment: This is awesome, I have never seen this!

Comment: This is a great solution for projects that live in repos!

Comment: The `'exrc'` option already allows doing something very similar to this.  It will load a `.vimrc`/`.exrc`/`.gvimrc` in the current working directory.

Comment: The comment about `exrc` should be the right answer. Everything else seems o hacky and complicated.

Comment: Using `exrc` is nice, but I do appreciate getting the correct file even when I'm not in the same working directory as the file I'm editing.

Comment: How secure is this? It seems like for example if you download some malicious code it could put a `.vim` in the current folder, which your mini-plugin would read. I suppose if you download malicious code all bets are off but this seems to make it easier.

Comment: Any idea how to look for a .vim file in the file's directory and each parent directory until one is found?

Comment: @Shovas You could use vim-rooter so that your pwd is set to the project's root directory. From there, either directly use the .vim file there, or then optionally check all directories down till the current directory and use the last .vim file you find - depending on what you want

Answer (score 35):

You can also put [autocommands](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_40.txt.html#40.3) in your `.vimrc` which set specific options on a per-path basis.

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile /path/to/project1/* setl sw=4 et
au BufRead,BufNewFile /path/to/project2/* setl sw=3 noet
```

Comment: This is great when you are not in control of the repository so that you cannot put ".vim.custom" files in there. I like that it keeps the repository clean. Thanks. Disclaimer: if the path keeps changing in a non-pattern friendly manner, then the ".vim.custom" version is possibly nicer assuming one can modify the repository.

Answer (score 17):

Plugin doing the right thing:
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=441

“This plugin searches for local vimrc files in the filesystem tree of the currently opened file. By default it searches for all ".lvimrc" files from the file's directory up to the root directory and loads them in reverse order. The filename and amount of loaded files is customizable through global variables.”

Comment: And the github version also supports loading with pathogen too :-)

Comment: Another similar plugin is localrc.vim; it also allows filetype-specific per-directory settings; I find it indispensable. http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3393

Answer (score 12):

Assuming your fellow developers won't complain about it, you can always add vim settings to each file in the comments.

```
/*
 * vim:ts=4:sw=4:expandtab:...
 */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ...
```

Comment: I'm the only *ahem* enlightened dev on most of my teams, so no one should mind. 
This is a really neat per file solution.

Comment: I prefer adding them at the bottom so that they are unobtrusive, but I guess that's a matter of style.

Answer (score 6):

I created an open-sourced tool for just this purpose. Forget the headers, scanning, configurations, and local vimrc files.

Try swim.

## Swim

`swim` is a quick tool for switching vimrc files and creating convenient aliases. Here's a short usage list. See the [Github repo](https://github.com/dawsonbotsford/swim) for a walkthrough gif and download instructions:

#### Usage

```
swim add ~/dotfiles/myVimrc favorite    #Add new swim alias
swim ls                                 #Show available swim aliases
swim add https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dawsonbotsford/swim/master/exampleVimrcs/vimrcWikia.vim example
swim with favorite         #Set alias favorite as primary .vimrc
swim with main             #Set alias main as primary .vimrc
```

#### Read More

https://github.com/dawsonbotsford/swim

Answer (score 4):

After trying out the localvimrc plugin suggested by the previous poster, I very much like having non-futzy per-project control over vim settings.

It does ask confirmation before loading a .lvimrc file by default but there is a setting to automatically load .lvimrc files. Some might see this as a security hole, but it works as advertised.

I chose to .gitignore the .lvimrc files. Alternatively you can check them in as a form of shared settings (tab/space expansion, tabstops, other project-specific settings).

Comment: This script is amazing: https://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-local-vimrc. 1) It now only asks once and marks the file hash as OK. 2) It transverses the directory tree from root to current dir, sourcing closer higher priority files last.

Comment: Why add the `.lvimrc` file to `.gitignore`? The point is that everyone who uses vim and has the plugin installed gets the same settings.

Comment: @nyuszika7h some settings must be enforced, while others are purely personal. For settings that must be enforced to everyone, EditorConfig is even better as it is editor agnostic: https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vim

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [sledge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5092912/1260304) the usage of that plug-in is the best option I have seen and use. jerseyboy commented that the utility recommended ask for confirmation before loading (ie. after opening every file). To avoid this just set at your main `.vimrc` the list of local `.lvimrc` files:

`let g:localvimrc_whitelist='/development/kernel/.lvimrc'`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation on jamessan's

```
function! ConditionalLoad()
    let cwd = getcwd()
    if getcwd() =~ $HOME . "/src/mobile"
        so $HOME/.vim.mobile
    endif
endfunction
autocmd VimEnter * call ConditionalLoad()
```

I will frequently launch vi without a specific file that I'm jumping to so this enables loading config conditionally based on the current working directory. Downside is that the config isn't applied based on file but off of working directory.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. As an example of usage: I placed this code in `~/.vimrc`, changed `/src/mobile` to my Symfony projects directory (in my case it was `/www/symfony`) and modified `.vim.mobile` to `.vim.symfony` then placed new .vimrc config inside `~/.vim.symfony` file

Answer (score 1):

> *I work in several groups, each of which has its own tab/indentation/spacing standards in C.*

I work with all sorts of open source, all at the same time. It's not practical to be creating separate `.vimrc` files and reconfiguring the formatting standards. More than a decade ago, I finally got tired of dealing with the editor configuration and wrote a program called [`autotab`](http://www.kylheku.com/cgit/c-snippets/tree/autotab.c) to handle it.

When `autotab` is set up with Vim suggested, each time you load a file into Vim, `autotab` is invoked on it, and the Vim settings output `autotab` are passed to a `:set` command.

`autotab` reads several thousand lines from the file, analyzes them and determines the settings for the `expandtab`, `tabstop` and `shiftwidth` parameters.

It figures out whether the file uses hard tabs or just spaces for indentation, and it figures out the indentation size. If the file is indented with tabs, it figures out the right tab size, based on rendering the file sample using various tab sizes and judging it according to heuristics like line-over-line alignment of internal elements.

It works well enough that I stopped tweaking the algorithm years ago. If it gets confused, it's almost always because the file has formatting issues, such as the use of multiple conventions at the same time.

It is also "agnostic" of the file type and works well with a variety of different languages. I use it not only over C, but shell scripts, Lisp, Makefiles, HTML, and what have you.

Note that it doesn't handle other parameters of formatting that may be project-specific, like for instance, in C files, whether `case` labels in a `switch` statement are indented or not, or whether wrapped function argument lists are simply indented, or aligned to the opening parenthesis of the argument list. Vim does have settings for that sort of thing, and so the program could be plausibly extended to analyze the style and output those parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) for switching configuration (any dotfiles, not only `.vimrc`)

Install `stow`:

```
$ apt install stow
```

Create multiple directories for each configurations:

```
~$ ls -d ~/dotfiles/vim*
vim-all vim-webdev vim-go
```

Put different `.vimrc`'s in them:

```
$ find ~/dotfiles -name .vimrc
/home/username/vim-golang/.vimrc
/home/username/vim-webdev/.vimrc
/home/username/vim-all/.vimrc
```

Now you can instantinate vim-golang config with this command (should be run inside dotfiles directory):

```
~$ cd ~/dotfiles

dotfiles$ stow -v vim-golang
LINK: .vimrc => dotfiles/vim-golang/.vimrc
```

Now it's linked:

```
$ cd ~ && ls -l .vimrc 
.vimrc -> dotfiles/vim-golang/.vimrc
```

If you need to switch config, just re-`stow` it:

```
~$ cd dotfiles

dotfiles$ stow -v -D vim-golang
UNLINK: .vimrc

dotfiles$ stow -v vim-webdev
LINK: .vimrc => dotfiles/vim-webdev/.vimrc

$ cd ~ && ls -l .vimrc 
.vimrc -> dotfiles/vim-webdev/.vimrc
```

More reading of it here: [Managing dotfiles with GNU stow](https://alexpearce.me/2016/02/managing-dotfiles-with-stow/)

**Pros**: pretty simple, no vim plugin dependencies, can be used for managing all dotfiles, not only `.vimrc`.

**Cons**: configs are independent of each other, you need to manage/update each of them separately (if you dont switch/update you configs too often - it'll not be the issue).

Answer (score 0):

Looking for mostly the same issue I also found the Sauce plug-in: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3992

It claims:

> Sauce is a lightweight manager for multiple vimrc files, which can be used to load different settings for different environments. In short, you can maintain lots of different vim settings files and only load the one(s) you need when you need them.

I find it particularly interesting that it keeps it configuration all in its data directory instead of expecting the user to sprinkle dotfiles across the filesystem. This though often rather a metter of personal taste.

I have yet to test it though.