# Override the .vimrc file in specific instances

Tags: ide, vim

I am looking to make vim function more closely to an IDE in specific situations. To do this I plan to write a Perl script called jvim that is passed a workspace path and have it open a java specific instance of my modified vim. I would then extend this for other file types.

What I would like to do is have a .jvimrc that is loaded in preference to the standard .vimrc. this would then lead to me having plvim with a .plvimrc and pyvim with a .pyvimrc.

This should be fairly straight forward. I would also be looking to map commands to run scrips such as :newclass, :newinterface, :newproject and :newpackage but i think you get the idea.

Any advice you could give as well as the .vimrc overriding would be great.

Comment: Are you just looking for filetype plugins? (`:help ftplugin`)

Comment: I was looking for a bit more than that as i am looking for project management. I have a good project management plugin but i want to make sure that I conserve a good path structure, similar to eclipse. This is why i would like to write scripts for control. For the .*vimrc files, I merely was looking for a way of customizing the plugins loaded and the options selected when they load.

Comment: [Possible duplicated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889602/multiple-vim-configurations)