# Settings preferences to pyflakes (with python-mode in vim)

Tags: python, vim, python-mode, pyflakes

I'm getting lots of errors I don't care about: mostly this kind:

```
fabfile.py|2 error| W0611 'os' imported but unused [pyflakes]
```

when I import something I'm going to use later but not yet

Is there a way (similar to a .jshintrc file when using jshint) file to Silence certain pyflakes errors warnings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See *:help 'g:pymode_lint_ignore* in **Vim**.  For your case, add the following to your **vimrc**.

```
let g:pymode_lint_ignore = "W0611"
```

Comment: Thanks defining a .pylint file would do the same job? I don't like the idea of a global .vimrc ignore. I would like to control this per project

Comment: Answering that question is above my paygrade, but here on SO, there's a good answer on [multiple vim configurations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889602/multiple-vim-configurations) including a section on per project *vimrc*.

Comment: Thanks, I know about .vim.local or .vim.custom options. I'll accept the answer since It answers my direct questions (and solves my annoying problem) but I would really prefer to seperate this. I suspect python-mode using underneath one of the python linters. if so, removing the linting config outside vim would be advisable since  it would allow me to use another tool in the future

Comment: Python mode has its only version of pylint in *pymode/libs/pylama/lint/pylama_pylint*.  It uses the **pylint.rc** file in that directory, plus passes in as options whatever is specified in `g:pymode_lint_ignore`, `g:pymode_lint_select` and `g:pymode_lint_checkers`.  I don't believe it'll check the buffer's *cwd* *pylintrc* file.

Comment: 2018 - that syntax didn't work for me, `let g:pymode_lint_ignore = ['W0611']` did.