# Splitting up vimrc to work without plugins

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I work on multiple machines, the biggest challenge is when working on a server without the ability to use my plugins.

What I am trying to do is take my vimrc and separate all the plugin specific mappings, functions, plugin calls etc... So that way I can use them when I need them and not worry about them in server environments. This is where my lack of vim knowledge comes into play.

Here is my .vimrc, I was thinking of making a file for Plugins, and one for configs of the plugins.

```
"-- Main / Behaviours -------------------------------------------------------
set nocompatible
set background=dark

filetype off

"-- Files & Directories -----------------------------------------------------
set nobackup            " do not make backups
set noswapfile          " no swapfile

"-- General & UI Settings ---------------------------------------------------
colorscheme solarized   " set the colorscheme

" set t_Co=256            " force terminal to 256 colors
" let g:solarized_termcolors=256

"set cursorcolumn        " highlights the current column
"set cursorline          " highlights the current line

set fileformats=unix,mac
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set lazyredraw          " redraw only when needed
set ls=2                " always show the status line
set mouse=a             " use mouse everywhere
set noerrorbells        " don't make a noise
set number              " show line numbers by default
set ruler               " show current position along the bottom
set scrolloff=999       " keep the cursor vertically centered
set showcmd             " show command being typed
set showmode            " display mode (INSERT/REPLACE/etc.)
set title               " Display name of file being edited

"set statusline=%F%m%r%h%w\[FORMAT=%{&ff}]\[TYPE=%Y]\[ASCII=\%03.3b]\[HEX=\%02.2B]\ [WC:%{WordCount()}][POS=%04l,%04v][%p%%]\[LEN=%L]
"set viminfo='20,\"100,:20,%,n~/.viminfo"

"-- Searching ----------------------------------------------------------------
set ignorecase          " case insensitive searching by defalt
set incsearch           " show search matches while typing
set hlsearch            " highlight search results
set smartcase           " case insensitive if using capital letter
set wrapscan            " wrap around file when searching

"-- Text Formatting & Layout Settings ----------------------------------------
set autoindent          " always set autoindenting on
set copyindent          " copy the previous indentation on autoindenting
set expandtab           " use spaces instead of tabs
set nocindent           " turn off c indenting
set nowrap              " turn off line wrapping
set pastetoggle=<f2>    " toggle paste
set shiftwidth=2        " match shifting to indenting
set showmatch           " show matching bracket [{(< >)}]
set smartindent         " extra level of indentation in some cases
set smarttab            " insert tabs start of line according to shiftwidth
set softtabstop=2       " indent 2 spaces by default
"set spell              " turn on spellcheck
set spellsuggest=5      " limit spell suggest to top 5 words
set tabstop=2           " set tab to 2 spaces

"-- Wildmenu ------------------------------------------------------------------
set wildmenu            " make tab completion for files buffers act like bash
set wildmode=list:longest,full
set wildignore=*.dll,*.o*.obj,*.bak,*.exe,*.pyc,\*.jpg,*.gif,*.png

"=============================================================================
" HIGHLIGHTING & PLUGIN SETTINGS {{{
"=============================================================================
syntax on

"set list listchars=trail:_
"set listchars=tab:·\ ,trail:·,extends:»,precedes:«
":highlight SpecialKey ctermfg=darkgrey ctermbg=yellow

" don't show tabs in html,xml
autocmd filetype html,xml set listchars-=tab:>.

" remove bracket highlighting
let g:loaded_matchparen = 1

" syntastic - chain multiple php checkers
let g:syntastic_php_checkers=['php', 'phpcs', 'phpmd']

" nerdtree - tabs open on console startup
" let g:nerdtree_tabs_open_on_console_startup=1

"=============================================================================
" CUSTOM KEYMAPPINGS
"
" <leader>dos: remove dos line-endings
" <leader>e: toggle NERDTree
" <leader>ev: edit vimrc
" <leader>sv: source vimrc
" <leader>l: toggle set list
" <leader>md: markdown to html
" <leader>mds: markdown to html and save as .html
" <leader>sn: set nopaste
" <leader>sp: set paste
" <leader>rw: remove trailing whitespace
" <leader>ww: toggle wrap
" <leader><space>: turn off search highlight
" <F4>: toggle spellcheck
" <F6>: toggle no linenumbers
"
"=============================================================================
let mapleader=","

nmap <leader>dos :%s/\r//g
nmap <leader>e :NERDTreeToggle<cr>
nmap <leader>l :set list!<cr>
nmap <leader>md :%! /usr/local/bin/markdown/ --html4tags <cr>
nmap <leader>mds :%! /usr/local/bin/markdown/ --html4tags <cr>:saveas %:r.html<cr>
nmap <leader>sn :set nopaste<cr>
nmap <leader>sp :set paste<cr>
nmap <leader>rw :%s/\s\+$//e
nmap <leader>ww :set wrap!<cr>
nmap <leader><space> :nohlsearch<cr>

" Quickly edit/reload the vimrc file
nmap <silent> <leader>ev :vsplit $MYVIMRC<CR>
nmap <silent> <leader>sv :so $MYVIMRC<CR>

map <F4> :setlocal spell! spelllang=en_us<cr>
map <F6> :setlocal nonumber!<cr>

"=============================================================================
" TEMPLATES & CUSTOM VIM FILETYPE SETTINGS {{{
"=============================================================================
autocmd! BufNewFile * silent! or ~/.vim/templates/%:e.tpl

" create a file in ftplugin/filetype.vim for specific settings
au BufRead,BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.text,*.txt set filetype=text
au BufRead,BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.md set filetype=markdown
au BufRead,BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.jade set filetype=pug
au BufRead,BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.pug set filetype=pug
au BufRead,BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.coffee set filetype=coffee

let g:pencil#wrapModeDefault = 'soft'   " default is 'hard'

augroup pencil
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType markdown,mkd call pencil#init()
  autocmd FileType text         call pencil#init({'wrap': 'hard'})
augroup END

"=============================================================================
" VIM FUNCTIONS
"=============================================================================
function! WordCount()
   let s:old_status = v:statusmsg
   let position = getpos(".")
   exe ":silent normal g\<c-g>"
   let stat = v:statusmsg
   let s:word_count = 0
   if stat != '--No lines in buffer--'
     let s:word_count = str2nr(split(v:statusmsg)[11])
     let v:statusmsg = s:old_status
   end
   call setpos('.', position)
   return s:word_count
endfunction

func! WordProcessorMode()
  set nonumber
  set tw=80
  set formatoptions=1
  set noexpandtab
  set wrap
  set spell spelllang=en_us
  set linebreak
  set nolist
  set complete+=s
  set formatprg=par
endfu
com! WP call WordProcessorMode()

"=============================================================================
" VIM PLUG SETUP & CONFIGS
"=============================================================================

if empty(glob('~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim'))
  silent !curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
        \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
  autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall | source $MYVIMRC
endif

call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Plug 'bling/vim-airline'
Plug 'godlygeek/tabular'
Plug 'jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs'
Plug 'junegunn/goyo.vim'
Plug 'nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides'
Plug 'reedes/vim-pencil'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plug 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plug 'tpope/vim-commentary'
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
Plug 'tpope/vim-surround'

" Experimental Plugins

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call plug#end()              " required


" Brief help
" :PlugList          - list configured bundles
" :PlugInstall(!)    - install(update) bundles
" :PlugSearch(!) foo - search(or refresh cache first) for foo
" :PlugClean(!)      - confirm(or auto-approve) removal of unused bundles
"
" NOTE: comments after Plugin command are not allowed..
```

Probably everything below the basic configurations I will move so I can have a more natural vimrc on servers.

Comment: You can conditionally source another file which has configurations related to plugins

Comment: Seems like an ideal way to do that. I just for some reason didn't think it would be that simple. Thanks for the help, trying it now

Comment: Learning to use Vim without plugins would be a much better idea.

Comment: I can use vim fine without plugins. But it makes it easier to write code, when I need to do devops work native vim is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your `vimrc` in to two.

1. `.vimrc` where you have basic configurations
2. Another file say `vimrc-plugin-configs` where you have everything related to plugin.

Now in your `.vimrc`, source `vimrc-plugin-configs` if it exists

```
if filereadable("/path/to/vimrc-plugin-configs")
   source /path/to/vimrc-plugin-configs
endif
```

Also if the file is in the same directory as `.vimrc` you don't have to provide path

Do take a look at this question too. It has a lot more advanced solutions.
[How to switch between multiple vim configurations with a command or local vimrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889602/how-to-switch-between-multiple-vim-configurations-with-a-command-or-local-vimrc/14403959#14403959)

Comment: It seems to be working for the most part. I am not catching the plugins in the ~/Sites directory, but when I open up vim elsewhere it seems to be working. Probably a path issue on my end, I will check out the other solutions you linked as well. Thank you.

Comment: lol. Thanks, that baby was like 3 years in the making. Still trying to improve upon it of course.